# prevent VNC-Session from using graphical.target | CentOS Stream 8 RHEL 8

Tags: centos, rhel, vnc

I'm setting up a homeserver and I'm running into the following issue.

- using `tiger-vnc`
- using CentOS Stream 8
- using root-user

When I start the Server the still connected display shows the `localhost login:`
from the `multi-user.target`
but when I connect via vnc, I get the desktop environment for the root user.
So I only want to start the desktop environment manually, when I really need it. What am I doing wrong? I thought setting the the `systemctl set-default` to `multi-user.target` prevents VNC from starting the Session into `graphical.target`. What do I need to mind and change for the future?

here the `get-default` result

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl get-default
multi-user.target
```

here the vnc service wich is enabled with the parameter `:1`

```
[Unit]
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/vncsession-start %i
PIDFile=/run/vncsession-%i.pid
SELinuxContext=system_u:system_r:vnc_session_t:s0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

here the result of `systemctl status vncserver@\:1.service`

```
vncserver@:1.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:1.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-12-12 12:03:05 CET; 21min ago
  Process: 1139 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/vncsession-start :1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1157 (vncsession)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 100263)
   Memory: 2.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-vncserver.slice/vncserver@:1.service
           ‣ 1157 /usr/sbin/vncsession root :1

Dec 12 12:03:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Remote desktop service (VNC)...
Dec 12 12:03:05 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Remote desktop service (VNC).
```

Answer (score 0):

Your systemd unit runs the VNC server as root (since there is no user defined), and you’ve indicated that it launches with multi-user.target, so that’s when it starts. There’s nothing in your service that is related to graphical.target.

I suggest you read the `/usr/share/doc/tigervnc/HOWTO.md` file on properly setting up the systemd service ([online version here](https://git.centos.org/rpms/tigervnc/blob/c8/f/SOURCES/HOWTO.md)).

Basically, you’ll set up specific display / user mappings in `/etc/tigervnc/vncserver.users`, and then start them by running `systemctl start vncserver@:1` to launch the user session associated with display 1.